# How to setup REST API in Codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am creating the REST API using codeigniter. I downloaded this library and installed in my application. It works great! https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

But I have an doubt. As per this library. I have 4 functoins

1. GET
2. POST
3. PUT
4. DELETE

I understand the functionality of each POST method but what I concern is how to write the validation and other things in the REST API.

Example: I have created the controller User.php

```
class User extends REST_Controller {

     public function __construct() 
     {
        parent::__construct();               
     }

     // Get multile / individual users records and perform search also.
     public function index_get()
     {  
         $this->response('get / search users', REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
     }

     // User Registration / Login
     public function index_post()
     {   
         echo 'create';
     }

     // User Information Update
     public function index_put()
     {
         echo 'update';
     }

     // User Delete
     public function index_delete()
     {
         echo 'delete';
     }    
}
```

I tested in postman post method works fine.

Here is my question. I have the following functionality for user.

1. Register
2. Login
3. Forgot Password
4. Change Password
5. Update Profile

I think except Register other functions are posted with PUT method?
In the PUT / POST method do I have to write all validations and database operation buy identity the post method variable using action likes register, login, forgot-password etc.,

In admin I want to get active or inactive users, find by email or name. this kind of operations where we have to write?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the basic validation on client-side, and if you need something to validate on server-side from the database you can manage the same in rest API.

1. Register - this should be done on client-side
2. Login - This can be done at server side by reading post parameter and validating same from the database.
3. Change Password - Here again, password policy can be validated and client-side and other validation like do no use same password can be managed at server side
4. Update Profile - Client-side validation

For writing server-side validation

```
class User extends REST_Controller {

 public function __construct() 
 {
    parent::__construct();               
 }// User Registration / Login
 public function index_post()
 {   
     $username = $this->input->post('username');
     $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post("password"));
     $message = $this->Login_model->check_login($username,$password);
     $this->response($message);
 }
}
```